# Gearman connection issue

Tags: centos, supervisord, gearman

Last night I had a problem with connection between Gearman server and jobs server, servers are on separated machines.
There was good job in Gearman queue, but it wasn't executing.

Job server uses Supervisor for running processes, and all processes were in 'RUNNING' status and they waited job from Gearman.

We are using Gearman v1.1.8, Centos 6.6.

Problems started after this message in log:

```
ERROR 2016-08-03 20:36:11.000000 [  main ] Timeout occured when calling bind() for 0.0.0.0:4730 -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:679
```

Comment: Did you try restarting the gearman server process?

Comment: It worked after command: "restart all" and I did like that. 
But why processes didn't reestablish connection or just change status to 'FATAL' because we have alarms for 'FATAL' status.